# Switch name type in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

How can I switch from "numberOfVoters" to "number-of-voters"?
Is there some hotkey or extenstion for this?

Before

```html
<div class="numberOfVoters"></div>
```

After (by pressing some hotkey)

```html
<div class="number-of-voters"></div>
```

Comment: There is no action available that would do this sort of transformation.

Comment: There are some plugins that can do similar things, but they oriented on actual coding (Java/PHP/etc) and do not have this specific transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [String Manipulation](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162?pr=idea) plug-in which does some conversions to the strings, like **Convert selected text to Camel Case**.

It probably doesn't support exactly what you need, but you can try enhancing it with the custom manipulations and then submit a patch to the original developers. It should be easier than starting your own plugin from scratch.